# PCA for retrieval from absolute values

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, random-matrices, parameter-estimation

I have given $(x_i)_{i=1}^n$ $d$-dimensional iid. random variables with $x_i\sim\mathcal N(0,I_d)$ and $y_i=|\langle x_i,\theta\rangle|$ with $\theta\in\mathbb R^d$.

**First I have to assume** that $\|\theta\|_2=1$ and define $\hat\theta$ as the maximal eigenvector of the matrix $\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 x_i x_i^T$.

Now I have to prove that $\hat\theta$ is a consistent estimator of $\theta$.

**My ideas:**

That means I have to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} P(\|\hat\theta-\theta\|_2\geq\varepsilon)=0\quad \forall\theta\in\mathbb R^d$.

I guess the first thing to do is to find a explicit representation of $\hat\theta$ depending on $n$. Maybe the [min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) could be helpfull.

**In the second part** I have to provide an estimator for arbitrary $\theta\in\mathbb R^d$ based on the $\hat\theta$ from above and show its consistency.

For this case there was also a hint to construct a random matrix $Z$ for a pair $(x,y)$ such that $E[Z] =\sqrt\frac2\pi(\theta^*\otimes\theta^*+I_d)$.

The Exercise can similarly be found on page 257 in [Wainwright](https://doi.org/10.1017/9781108627771), Exercise 8.7. I hope someone can help me. Greetings

Comment: I wonder if it would help to show first that the distribution of $y_i$ converges to a certain normal distribution as $n$ grows. $\qquad$